# Laravel : Cant Create Multiple Data Relation with Foreach

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-excel

I have a problem when creating data with ‍the `Maatwebsite/excel‍‍‍` import. In my import class, I want to create data with the relation, when I try the `dd` variable that contains child data its works just fine, but when I ‍`saveMany()` the data returns null and error.

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'description' cannot be null

**Here is my code:**

```
public function collection(Collection $rows) {
    $parent = Parent::create([
        'name' => $this->name,
        'slug' => $this->slug,
        'month' => $this->month,
    ]);

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $item = new Child([
            'description' => $row['description'],
            'status' => $row['status'],
        ]);
        $items[] = $item;
    }
    $parent->childs()->saveMany($items);
}
```

Comment: better if you add dd($rows) output to the question.as per error description is null in any one of the row

Comment: It would be great! if you can share table structure or child relationship method information.
Possibly you are missing relationship key in your child records.

Comment: Add `if ($row['description'] == null) {dd(true)}` to `foreach ($rows as $row) {`. Does loop finish or you get dd()?

Comment: thank you for giving me an advices of my problem. I've done solving my problem by using implements toModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probabily your $row['description'] in foreach have null value.

Edit you loop code like this

```
 foreach ($rows as $row) {
        if(!empty($row['description]))
        {
          $item = new Child([
            'description' => $row['description'],
            'status' => $row['status'],
          ]);
         $items[] = $item;
        }
    }
```

And also edit the last line

```
if(!empty($items))
  $parent->childs()->saveMany($items);
```